# Running EFA and CFA on the same population at different time point

Tags: factor-analysis, confirmatory-factor

The participants filled in the questionnaires at 6-month intervals. Since the questionnaires detect changes, which I think would not affect the factor structure. (And the EFA on the 1st time point do provide good fit on the 2nd time point.) But as they are filled in by the same population, would there be potential problem about the variability will likely be lower compare to a completely different population? Should I run EFA and CFA split half on the population at only one time point instead?

Which leads to another question, how long would the interval be good enough for treating as a different set of response?

Comment: Do you mean “population” or “sample”? Are these the same participants?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I mean the sample population. The same participants filled the questionnaires at 6-month intervals.

Comment: What is your goal here? To establish the factor structure of the measure, or to measure changes in participants’ scores over time?

Comment: Obtain the factor structure by EFA first and the try to establish it by CFA. It will be used to measure changes over time. (so ultimately will run time series sem.)

Comment: I think replicating the factor structure in the same sample shows reliability, which is valuable, but not necessarily generalizability. How confident are you that your sample is representative of the population? Are you measuring something more trait like or state like?

Comment: it is representative. what's the difference between measuring trait or state like? i guess it is more state like for our measures.....

Comment: Participant scores on a trait-like measure will be more likely to stay consistent over long periods of time, making it less likely for the same sample to be a “fresh look.”